# ConcurrentHashMap with synchronized

Tags: java, concurrency

I am maintaining some legacy code and found some implementation with `synchronized` key-word on `ConcurrentHashMap`. It seem unnecessary to me:

```
public class MyClass{

    private final Map<MyObj, Map<String, List<String>>> conMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    //...

    //adding new record into conMap:
    private void addToMap(MyObj id, String name, String value){
        conMap.putIfAbsent(id, new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
        Map<String, List<String>> subMap = conMap.get(id);
        synchronized(subMap){                            // <-- is it necessary?
            subMap.putIfAbsent(name, new ArrayList<>());
            subMap.get(name).add(value);
        }
    }

    //...

    public void doSomthing((MyObj id){
        List<Map<String, List<String>>> mapsList = new LinkedList<>();
        for(MyObj objId: conMap.keySet()){              
            if(objId.key1.equals(id.key1)){
                mapsList.add(conMap.get(objId));
            }
        }

        for(Map<String, List<String>> map: mapsList){
            synchronized(map){                       // <-- is it necessary?
                if(timeout <= 0){
                    log(map.size());
                    for(List<String> value: map.values(){
                        log(id, value);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    int sum = 0;
                    for(map.Entry<String, List<String>> val: map.entrySet()){
                        sum += val.getValue().size();
                    }
                    log(sum);
                    map.wait(timeout);
            }
    }

    //...

}
```

So, is it reasonable to use `synchronized` key on object that already concurrent? Or those are two different things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case:

```
    synchronized(subMap){                            // <-- is it necessary?
        subMap.putIfAbsent(name, new ArrayList<>());
        subMap.get(name).add(value);
    }
```

the `synchronized` is necessary.  Without it, you could have two threads simultaneously updating the same `ArrayList` instance.  Since `ArrayList` is not thread-safe, the `addToMap` method would not be thread-safe either.

In this case:

```
        synchronized(map){                       // <-- is it necessary?
            if(/*condition*/){
                log(map.size());
                for(List<String> value: map.values(){
                    log(id, value);
                }
            }
            else{
                int sum = 0;
                for(map.Entry<String, List<String>> val: map.entrySet()){
                    sum += val.getValue().size();
                }
                log(sum);
                map.wait(timeout);
        }
```

the `synchronized` is necessary.

- In the `if` branch, the `log` method (or something called from it) will probably call `ArrayList::toString` which will iterate each `ArrayList`.  Without the synchronizing at the submap level, there could be a simultaneous `add` by another thread (e.g. an `addToMap` call).  That means that there are memory hazards, and a `ConcurrentModificationException` may be possible in the `toString()` method.
- In the `else` branch, the `size()` call is accessing a size field in each `ArrayList` in the submap. Without the synchronizing at the submap level, there could be a simultaneous `add` on one of those list.  That could cause the `size()` method to return a stale value.  In addition, you are not guaranteed to see map entries added to a submap while your are iterating it.  If either of those events happen, the `sum` could be inaccurate.  (Whether that is really an issue depends on the requirements for this method: inaccurate counts *could* be acceptable.)

Answer (score 2):

ConcurrentHashMap synchronizes each individual method call itself, so that no other thread can access the map (and possibly break the internal data structure of the map).

Synchronized block synchronizes two or more consecutive method calls, so that no other thread can modify the data structure between the calls (and possibly break the consistency of the data, with regards to the application logic).

Note that the synchornized block only works if all access to the HashMap is performed from synchronized blocks using the same monitor object.

Answer (score 2):

It is sort of necessary, as multiple threads may try to append to the same `ArrayList` at the same time. The `synchonized` is protecting against that happening as `ArrayList` is obviously not synchronized.

Since Java 8 we have `computeIfAbsent` which means the puts followed by gets they are doing can be simplified. I would write it like this, no synchronization required:

```
conMap.computeIfAbsent(id, k -> new ConcurrentHashMap<>())
    .computeIfAbsent(name, k -> new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>()) // or other thread-safe list
    .add(value);
```

Comment: @Lino ah, i missed that. Java 8 code *is* practically legacy by today's standards ;)

Comment: Thanks for your, answer. `computeIfAbsent` sounds interesting need to check it

Comment: But `synchronized` is on `subMap` how it protect the `ArrayList`?

Comment: @Eli If you synchronize access to the subMap, and -- crucially -- you only access the list **via** the subMap, then you will necessarily have to cross the synchonization barrier.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers don't adequately this bit...

```
   for(Map<String, List<String>> map: mapsList){
        synchronized(map){                       // <-- is it necessary?
            if(/*condition*/){
                ...iterate over map...
            }
            else {
                ...iterate over map...
            }
        }
   }
```

Is it necessary? Hard to tell.

What is `/*condition*/` ?  Does synchronizing on `map` prevent some other thread A from changing the value of `/*condition*/` after thread B has tested it, but before or while thread B is performing either of the two branches?  If so, then the `synchronized` block could be very important.

How about those iterations? Does synchronizing on `map` prevent some other thread A from changing the contents of the map while thread B is iterating? If so, then the `synchronized` block could be very important.

Comment: `if(timeout <= 0)`